# Checking against an API (without the data being saved) in create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to run a check against a web API as the user creates the record. Is there a way to do it? The alternative is to create a new action that is redirected from the create action but i would like to avoid this.

**Controller code**:

```
  def create
   @reload = Reload.new(params[:reload])
   time = Time.now
   complete_date = time.strftime("%d%m%y%H%M%S")
   reload_count = Reload.all.count
   reload_count_id = reload_count.to_s.rjust(5, '0')
   generated_reference_id = complete_date + reload_count_id
   @reload.reference_id = 'R'+generated_reference_id

   template = Addressable::Template.new("http://host.mydomain.com/remote_api.php{?query*}")
   url = template.expand({ 'query' => { 'msisdn' => '6#{@reload.number}', 'type' => 'json' } })
   csgdata = JSON.load(open(url))
   isregistered = csgdata['IsRegistered']

   if (isregistered == TRUE)
       flash[:notice] = "It is working!"
   end

   if user_signed_in?
     @reload.user_id = current_user.id
     @reload.guest = false
   else
     @reload.guest = true
   end
   respond_to do |format|
     if @reload.save
        format.html { redirect_to checkout_reload_path(@reload) }
     else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @reload.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
  end
```

The code above implements rest_client and addressable gem to try to check from an API if the number entered into the system is available.

Comment: What do you mean: immediately after the object is created or after the whole action 'create' is finished?

Comment: immediately after the object is created to check against an API for information, before the whole 'create' option is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your model, use the callback **after_create**:

```
Class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
after_create :foo

  def foo
    # here you can check whatever you want after the object was really 
    # created (only at the first time then. If you want to check every 
    # time after the object is saved, then use #after_save)
  end
```

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what your goal is, so you may additionally consider a custom validation on the model

Comment: I have solved the problem and am posting the answer. I wanted to check during the "create" action process and not after that.

Answer (score -1):

require "addressable/template"

```
def create
 @reload = Reload.new(params[:reload])

 template = Addressable::Template.new("http://localhost.localdomain/remote.php{?query*}")
  url = template.expand({ 'query' => { 'msisdn' => "6#{@reload.number}", 'type' => 'json' } })
  data = JSON.load(open(url))

  isregistered = data['IsRegistered']
  terminateddate = data['TerminatedDate']
  firstcalldate = data['FirstCallDate']
  onpeakaccountidexpiry = data['OnPeakAccountIDExpiryDate']

  if (isregistered == 'TRUE' && terminateddate != nil && firstcalldate != nil)
    if (onpeakaccountidexpiry > Time.now.to_s(:db))
     respond_to do |format|
       if @reload.save
         format.html { redirect_to checkout_reload_path(@reload) }
       else
         format.html { render action: "new" }
         format.json { render json: @reload.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
     end
    else
       redirect_to new_reload_path, flash: { error: "Your account is not active" }
       # flash[:error] = "Account is not active"
    end
  else
       redirect_to new_reload_path, flash: { error: "Your account is not registered" }
       # flash[:error] = "Your account is not registered"
  end
end
```

Comment: Glad you got it figured out, but TBH, that method is a steaming mess... You will be doing yourself a favor by attempting to reconcile your solution with that of @Tiago Farias. In addition to being more idiomatic, it is easier to test, and just a lot nicer to look at... There are many callbacks available, at most points of the process - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html.

Comment: I am afraid things like flash: or flash[:error] will not work when i use it in the model, though ActiveRecord callbacks is something that i would use, for example 'before_create' callback.

Comment: Flash is not used in the relevant section of code. You would want to move only selected portions of your code. You might search for "rails fat controller" for some interesting examples of how one might approach this.